How to define a variable first right after SSH into a remote server?
I want to redeploy a docker container via Jenkinsfile on a remote EC2, but I struggle to find a solution that works with ssh. I want to have to lookup if the container already exist and remove it first.
What I tried:
I wrote a script which works on my local machine but there is no need for ssh.
This is the working stage from my Jenkinsfile.
        stage('Deploy Docker container on HOST') {
            steps {
                script {
                    // Check if container exists
                    def containerId = sh(script: "docker ps --quiet --filter name=$CONTAINER_NAME", returnStdout: true).trim()

                    if (containerId.isEmpty()) {
                        echo "Container $CONTAINER_NAME not found. Skipping stop/remove steps."
                    } else {
                        echo "Stopping and removing existing container $CONTAINER_NAME ..."
                        sh "docker stop $CONTAINER_NAME"
                        sh "docker rm $CONTAINER_NAME"
                        sh "docker rmi $DOCKERH_REPO/$IMAGE_TAG:latest" // Remove leftover image if needed
                        sh "docker rmi $DOCKERH_REPO/$IMAGE_TAG:$BUILD_VERSION" // Remove leftover image if needed
                    }

                    // Always run the container regardless of previous existence
                    echo "Starting container $CONTAINER_NAME ..."
                    sh "$DOCKER_RUN"
                    sh "docker image prune --force"
                }
            }
        }


Now I would like to be able to do the same but on a remote server via SSH. I moved the cript to an external groovy for this stage to be more clean.
Stage
        stage('Deploy Docker container on EC2') {
            steps {
                script {
                    sshagent(['aws-ssh']) {
                        sh "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ec2-user@35.157.110.150 'xgs.buildEC2()'"
                    }
                }
            }
        }


jenkins.groovy script
def buildEC2() {
    // Check if container exists
    def containerId = sh(script: "docker ps --quiet --filter name=$CONTAINER_NAME", returnStdout: true).trim()

    if (containerId.isEmpty()) {
        echo "Container $CONTAINER_NAME not found. Skipping stop/remove steps."
    } else {
        echo "Stopping and removing existing container $CONTAINER_NAME ..."
        sh "docker stop $CONTAINER_NAME"
        sh "docker rm $CONTAINER_NAME"
        sh "docker rmi $DOCKERH_REPO/$IMAGE_TAG:latest" // Remove leftover image if needed
        sh "docker rmi $DOCKERH_REPO/$IMAGE_TAG:$BUILD_VERSION" // Remove leftover image if needed
    }

    // Always run the container regardless of previous existence
    echo "Starting container $CONTAINER_NAME ..."
    sh "$DOCKER_RUN"
    sh "docker image prune --force"
}

return this


Just deploying the container works good (executing commands like docker run with params etc).
What I fail to achieve is running the same logic from the former stage on the remote EC2 by defining the containerId variable first and running a conditional statement. I get this error:
bash: -c: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('
bash: -c: line 1: `def containerId = sh(script: \"docker ps --quiet --filter name=$CONTAINER_NAME\", returnStdout: true).trim()'

I tried encapsulating with single quotes and escaping but it did not work or my lack of knowledge hinders me to understand the right approach.
Any help would be much appreciated.
p.s. I am new to the SE world and still learning.

Do you mean that sh "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ec2-user@35.157.110.150 'xgs.buildEC2()'" is some pseudo code, it's not actually invoking ssh in shell with this parameters?

I defined "xgs" as external groovy script, it invokes the script fine. eg. If I put a simple echo command line it works.

echo is not a Groovy command, and neither is sh - those are Jenkins steps. Are you sure you are invoking them in an external groovy script?

Sorry I am still a beginner, not sure if I understand you. I should do ssh inside groovy script and just call the whole function?

so I reconfigured the step to use the ssh agent and just call the groovy script. Inside groovy I tested with the line sh "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ec2-user@35.157.110.150 echo \"something\"" escaping the quotes and the pipeline runs.
But how to include the whole script logic escapes me

You realize that echo \"something\" is bash echo, not groovy echo, right?

Thank you for helping me out. The whole command is inside shell and as long as those are simple shell commands they work. Do you have any suggestions how I would continue from here to be able to define the variable and conditional similar to the first code block in my question?

It looks like your writing some container orchestration. I would stop that and look at something like k8s or docker swarm.

Thank you, I plan to learn about that in the future. But for now I resorted to executing a wget which pulls a bash script from git and runs all needed commands.

After further tinkering I changed the logic and resorted to a workaround by simply executing a wget command in the jenkins file, which pulls a bash script from git and executes all needed commands.
Not really a direct answer to the question, but bottom line enables what I wanted to achieve. I also simplified the commands by utilizing docker-compose.
Jenkins stage:
        stage('Deploy Docker container on EC2') {
        steps {
            script {
                sshagent(['aws-ssh']) {
                    echo "Deploying Docker container on EC2  ..."
                    sh "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ec2-user@35.157.110.150 'bash -c \"\$(wget -qLO - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/juronja/DiluteRight/refs/heads/main/ec2-commands.sh)\"'"
                }
            }
        }
    }

bash script:
#!/bin/bash

# Downloading and overwriting the compose file
wget -O compose.yaml https://raw.githubusercontent.com/juronja/DiluteRight/refs/heads/main/compose.yaml

# Stoping and starting the container
docker-compose down
docker-compose up -d

